# how to reduce size of image so that it can fit to blob type..?

Tags: android

I'm compressing an image by using this code

```
     imageText=encodeToBase64(bitmap, Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100);
```

but when I store this image into my database and attribute type blobmedium then it takes too much time for displaying (loading) the image.
Even if my original image size is 32 Kb, it stores as 259 Kb in the database.

When I use tinyblob or blob type for image attribute in database it stores the value but does not show any results in the UI.

How can I reduce the size of image so that it fit to tinyblobb or blob?
So that I can store and fetch image successfully.

Comment: there is little to no compression done when the image quality is at 100%, you gotta scale it down :(

Comment: you should only save image path in database and load it later via path

Comment: thak you both olayinka and vivek..it will help me.

Comment: hii , I scaled down 100% to 30%  but it does not showing image when i fetch image from database.

Comment: If you you use base64 you are not compressing. Instead you create 30% more bytes to store. Very bad idea to use base64.

Comment: thank you @greenapps..could you please give an idea how i can reduce image size properly or an option to base64..?

Answer (score 0):

use the below code to compress an image:

```
Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

// call to base64 image conversion method:
String encodeToBase64 = bitmapToBase64(thumbnail);
```

and then encode it to the base64 format as:

```
private String bitmapToBase64(Bitmap bmp)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Note that:  A `BLOB` can be 65535 bytes maximum. If you need more consider using a `MEDIUMBLOB` for 16777215 bytes or a `LONGBLOB` for 4294967295 bytes